# Going back in time on Github?

Tags: github

How do I go back to a previous build? For example going back to the July 30 state?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "go back?"  Do you want to permanently go back to this commit?

Comment: Yeah revert to July 30 commit

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to functionally undo a series of commits in Git.  But given that the branch in question is published, and likely shared by several people, I would recommend using `git revert` here.  `git revert` adds *new* commits on top of your current branch which undo previous commits.  These revert commits can be thought of as mirror images of what was done in previous commits.  Something like this should work:

```
git revert 00bfe1b^..a013402
```

This should add two commits, one to undo the Aug-9 commit and one to undo the Aug-13 commit.

As a side note, you *could* have also done this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

This would have completely nuked the two commits on top of Jul-30.  *However*, this involves rewriting the history of the branch, which isn't desirable if other people may already be sharing this branch with you.  In this case, just play it safe and use `git revert`.

Comment: do i enter this in terminal..?  (sorry new to this). also what should "00bfe1b^..a013402"  <-- this part look like? thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2277916 The answer I gave you is intended to be done _locally_ from the Git bash.  You can probably do this from the GitHub website, but I wouldn't personally do that.  Just checkout your branch and then use `git revert` exactly as I have it.  Then, push your branch to GitHub.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. where do you find this value: 00bfe1b^..a013402  ?

Comment: These are the commit hashes, which are unique identifiers for each commit.  If you check your screenshot, you will see whence I got them.

Answer (score 1):

To view (browse the file tree) the repository state at a certain commit given at least the first four characters of commit's hash, the following URL schema for GitHub can be used (at the time of writing):

`https://github.com/{username}/{repository name}/tree/{hash}`

If you want to **hard reset** your GitHub repository to a specific commit, do a `git reset --hard {hash}` in your local (stored on your computer) repository then force push it to a remote repository (like GitHub) via `git push --force`.

Of course, hard resets are dangerous. You can `git revert` or `git reset` and `stash` unstaged changes, and I'm sure there are other ways to achieve similar effects.